# JAVA_HOME points to the wrong place

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-home

I seem to have an incorrectly specified JAVA_HOME variable. I can get around it for many things but now I am seem to be stuck. I am trying to use the Google App Engine and upload an application.

When I do so I get the error that the error:

> cannot find javac executable based on java.home, tried "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Java\bin\javac.exe"

I don't understand why it is looking there, doing echo %JAVA_HOME% gives me:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14

Which is where Java actually is. I am thinking my best hope might be to just put Java where it is looking for it - can you think of anything better.

Comment: Are you using the App Engine plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: I am using the App Engine plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's possibly a bug:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1226

There are lots of suggested workarounds/solutions, but [comment #24](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1226#c24) in the bug entry seems promising:

> The problem is that GAE plugin for
>   Eclipse is default configured with a
>   JRE instead of a JDK.
>
> To change this, do the following:
>
> Preferences > Java > Installed JRE's >
>   Add... For 'JRE Type' select 'Standard
>   VM' > Next > Directory: select your
>   JDK  directory (instead of JRE) (in my
>   case: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16 ), press OK.
>
> Now, you are back at 'Installed
>   JRE's', select the JDK here also.

Answer (score 1):

Double check for any typo in the JAVA_HOME path.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply add "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin" to your %PATH%