# Python is not recognized upgrading pip. How to upgrade?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I tried to upgrade pip in Python with command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, but I get this error in the command prompt on Windows:

```
'python' is not recognized as as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Kindly help.

Comment: A quick google search showed a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognised-as-a-command as well as many other links about the problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Python in your `PATH` environment variable. You should [add to your PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674051/70170) `;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts` (or wherever you installed your Python).

Alternatively, use `py -m pip` in place of `python -m pip`. If you have a late version of Python installed, `py` launcher will be in your path already.

For more details, read up on [using Python in Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).