# Android packaging with sencha touch 2 sdk tools?

Tags: android, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to make a .apk from my Sencha Touch 2 app. I am using default mvc app that i got from running sencha command `sencha app create MyApp /path/to/www/myapp` , in addition to this app, I created  debug `.keystore` from Android SDK. Also I created my own `packager.json` that is *valid JSON*. I Downloaded all Android Revisions, including *revision 17*. I am using Window 7 Ultimate x64 as my platform and Sencha Touch 2.0.0 GPLv3 as framework. **My problem is showing when trying to generate .apk with sencha command.** `sencha package run packager.json`.I have tried with android emulator turned on as instructed on Sencha Touch 2 Documentation.

Here is my packager.json, app frame and error image:

**Packager.json**

```
{
    "applicationName":"HelenaApp",
    "applicationId":"com.helena",
    "iconName":"icon.png",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "outputPath":"C:/wamp/www/Helena/HelenaAndroid",
    "inputPath":"C:/wamp/www/Helena",
    "webAppPath":"C:/wamp/www/Helena",
    "androidAPILevel":"13",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"AndroidEmulator",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"moj-key.keystore",
    "certificateAlias":"helena",
    "sdkPath":"C:/Android/android-sdk",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

**APP**

[image: Helena app frame]

**Error**

[image]

**EDIT:**
Thanks for answer, seems i got first problem solved, now I got another:

[image]

Seems It has something to do with java PATH as seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3394369/765628), any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

1. I edited path to my `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` JDK,
2. Previous path was path to Sencha SDK
3. Then I changed it back to Sencha, and i got error in console `ERROR: createProcessW`

*4. Regarding two Java instances, i have jdk7 in Program Files, and jdk6 in Program Files(x86) --**(FALSE)*** 
4. I have only one jdk (1.7.0_03)

[image]

Comment: you don't replace PATH, you need to ADD to existing

Comment: @Alexander Voloshyn -I'v modified path and added jdk path, separated by semicoln, still getting ERROR: CreateProcessW - The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: try using directly "stbuild package packager.json", that will run packager without sencha command wrapper.

Comment: We had something similar and it was related to java installation, what we did is removed all java installations jdk and jde and then installed jdk7, edited PATH variable so it includes "bin" folder of jdk7 and set JAVA_HOME variable also to point to jdk7 folder, after that everything worked fine.

Comment: will fix the problem?, how could sign the apk in touch sencha v1?

Answer (score 1):

1. You get into recursion, your output folder is inside the input folder, so once you copy file one more is created and so on, all you need to do is to specify your build folder somewhere else and remove it from inputPath
2. webAppPath was replaced by inputPath and now is ignored, you can remove it from your config safely.
3. "applicationId":"com.helena" is not valid, you have to have 3 components, for example "com.helena.app"

Comment: yes, it's a PATH problem, to fix this right click "My computer", select "properties", click advanced system settings and then in the system properties window click environment variables, then edit PATH variable and add path to the "bin" folder of your java installation, for example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16

Comment: Also make sure you have only one jdk installed otherwise there may be conflicts

Comment: what errors do you have? are you sure you added java bin path to PATH variable correctly? Did you remove anything from PATH what was already there? Post as much details as you have and we will figure this out

Comment: @Alexander Voloshyn i tired this way but im getting blank screen plzz see this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323516/including-sencha-touch-2-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The Problem arises only if the "PATH" variable doesn't contain `"C:\Windows\System32"`. Add this to the path and will solve the **CreateProcessW** Error on WIndows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have JAVA_HOME point to the JDK directory, not /bin in your system variables. (windows)
example:

JAVA_HOME         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

Also, I made the mistake of thinking the JDK was included in Java, which it is not, it needed to be downloaded and installed separately.