# Java Project using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

can you help me. I have created a project at NetBeans, then accidentally I have uninstalled my jdk. Then when I open my netbeans my project was gone, not eventually gone because my project is still my directory Documents/NetbeansProjects, but in the netbeans it was gone, it should have appread in the left side of the netbeans the project. I try to re- install netbeans and also jdk. the project was recovered, I imported the zip file of the project to the new netbeans, but when I try to Clean and Build the project to make a .exe file. It won't Build. Can someone HELP ME. 
**strong text**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S54Ky.png)

Comment: Have you checked whether the file javac.exe exists in the location that NetBeans is trying to run it?

Comment: try comments from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394369/getting-error-running-javac-exe-compiler-message-while-using-ant-in-eclipse

Comment: what message do you get when you try to build?

Comment: try to resetup the path of jre and jdk in NB

Comment: @efekctive, try to click the enter image description here. It is in there. it says error to run jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac.exe